# phpass FRAMEWORK- ERROR

Tags: php, database, encryption, hash, salt

I test the phpass framework, and in the examples [one to four in the demo], they work without any problem.

But in the example 5 and 6 I receive an error "An error occurred (Bad passphrase (check failed))." when I attempt to create a new user

I just test the demos, I don't do any alteration

What is the problem?

http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, hashing is *not* encryption.

Comment: ok, anyway, the issue is not that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be following the [bizarre stand-alone so-called "tutorial"](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords) article that the phpass authors wrote a bit ago.  I say "so-called" because it's not a tutorial at all, but a lengthy article on best practices when setting up an authentication system in PHP.

***The tutorial code is not part of the library***, and following it *will not help you use the library more effectively*.  Nevertheless, **it's a good article** and is actually worth reading and understanding.

The error `Bad passphrase (check failed)` is coming from the `pwqcheck` function, which attempts to find an external binary by that name.  The error can be triggered *either* by providing a low-quality password *or* by failing to have the program execute.  This is a rather poor design because it's not clear what's going on.

**Please go back to the article and re-read it from the top.**  If you missed the detail on what's going on in that function (or having it explained to you here did not immediately tell you what you must do to resolve the problem), then you're going to want to dive back in from the beginning to ensure that you have not missed any other details.

Comment: thanks charles, i just use the script to generate the pass :)